How to refresh the status value of the thermostat in real time?
I am developing the Google Home app to work almost the same as my existing thermostat app. Currently, the device list is fetching the thermostat value in real time once every 30 seconds. However, I tried using both sync and query on the thermostat screen, but the value is only shown in the log in my server, and it is not refreshed on the Google Home app. How can I refresh the controller screen on the Google Home app?
In the Google Home app(one device thermostat screen), when I press the settings button on the top right of the controller screen and press X, the QUERY-related logs are accumulated on my server, so
I used the following code to repeat
intent = action.devices.QUERY
However, only the text log shows the latest values ​​normally. The controller in the Google Home app did not refresh.
I also tried Sync, EXECUTE, but it was the same.
Currently, only the 'Thermetic Device List' screen in the Google Home app shows the latest values every 30 seconds. However, I want to automatically display the latest values (refresh concept) from time to time on the 'Single Thermostat Screen'.
...
switch (intet) {
                    case 'action.devices.SYNC':
                        sync({ uid, auth: accessTok, requestId: reqdata.reqId }, respon);
                        break;
                    case 'action.devices.QUERY':
                        query({ uid, auth: accessTok, requestId: reqdata.reqId, devices: input.payload.devices }, respon);
                        break;
                    case 'action.devices.EXECUTE':
                        exec({ uid, auth: accessTok, requestId: reqdata.reqId, commands: input.payload.commands }, respon);
                        break;
....

The relevant video is as follows
https://youtube.com/shorts/ru_d8fYkNmg?si=qSu4aEzP44KVqytc

Google Home app generally updates the controller data every 30 seconds within the same session unless you manually refresh the page. If you're experiencing significant delays, check if there are any adjustable refresh rate settings on your thermostat.
To ensure your Google Home app displays the most accurate and up-to-date thermostat information, make sure that Query and Report State are enabled.
These features allow your thermostat to communicate its current status to the Google Home app. Please ensure both are enabled in your thermostat's settings.

In the 'Favorite' and 'Device List' screens, at least once every 30 seconds is brought to the latest value and shown.(This is what I'm satisfied with)
However, Google Home App has not been able to refresh only the 'Temperature Controller Control Screen' to the latest value.
I'm trying to solve this phenomenon. Is there anything I missed?

Thank you for your response, it appears that support is not available
issuetracker.google.com/issues/369246559
